# Mark IDs that have a specific value across columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a variable 'check' with values 1/0. These should be assigned based on whether across columns V1 to V3 there is at least one value = 1 for each ID.

```
DF <- data.frame (ID= c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6), V1= c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0), 
V2= c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0), V3= c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0))
```

This is the code I am using but group by doesn't seem to work. It does seem to go across columns and mark as 1 all of those having at least one value of 1 but not by ID.

```
DF %>% dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(Check= case_when(if_any('V1':'V3',~.x!=0)~1,TRUE ~0)) %>% 
dplyr::ungroup()
```

So the output I am looking for is this one:

| ID | V1 | V2 | V3 | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Could you help?

Many thanks!

Edit: apologies, I have noticed a mistake in the output, it should be fine now.

Comment: The output is not very clear, why is for ID 3, have both rows 0?

Comment: the output does not seem to match with the text `these should be assigned based on whether across columns V1 to V3 there is at least one value = 1 for each ID.`

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach, but I basically want to see if each ID record has a 1 on all the variables. So ID3 data is split into two rows and neither of them have a 1 on the V3 variable, hence why the check column should be 0. Hope this clarifies

Comment: Instead of `case_when`, since you're just checking a simple logical test and converting to numeric, you can use `Check = as.numeric(if_any(V1:V3, ~.x != 0))`, or as a shortcut, `Check = +if_any(V1:V3, ~.x != 0)`

Comment: But in general it's still unclear what you're trying to do exactly. It seems like `if_any` is more designed for selecting columns...you might want `base::any`? As far as I can tell, the only ID that should have Check = 0 is ID = 6, since all the other IDs have at least one nonzero column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code

these are steps i followed

1. after grouping by ID column, derive new columns where if column is equal to 0 then change the value to NA, replace the 0 with NA
2. then retain the previous values to all the other rows so if the value is 1 it will be retained to other rows within the by group
3. then sum the values of all the three variables and if the sum of all 3 variable is 3 then derive check variable and update the value to 1
4. retain the 1 to other rows within the by group else set to zero

```r
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(across(starts_with('V'), ~ ifelse(.x==0, NA, .x), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
fill(starts_with('new')) %>% 
mutate(check=ifelse(rowSums(across(starts_with('new')))==3,1,0)) %>% 
fill(check, .direction = 'downup') %>% mutate(check=replace_na(check,0)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with('new'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Groups:   ID [6]
      ID    V1    V2    V3 check
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     0     1
 2     1     0     1     1     1
 3     1     0     0     0     1
 4     2     1     0     1     0
 5     3     1     1     0     0
 6     3     0     0     0     0
 7     4     0     1     0     0
 8     5     1     1     0     1
 9     5     0     0     1     1
10     6     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you but this output is not quite what I need. I need to check if there is a 1 across all the V1:V3 variables at the ID level, and some IDs such as 1,3,5 are spread onto more than one row. So for them, I need to check if across all the rows there is a 1 on all these 3 variables

Comment: I updated the answer as per the comment, please check

Comment: Some explanation would help here. The OP is still unclear, but what you're doing is hard to follow as well

Comment: updated the answer with the steps followed to get the result

Comment: Thank you so much jkatam, this worked as I wanted. I can have a headache free weekend now :) very interesting approach as well, I was not familiar with the fill command